# How do I type a class argument that's dependent on the value of another class argument?

Tags: typescript

In the following class, there is a link between the props `method` and `payload`. For example, if method is equal to `sendTransaction` then payload must be a `SendTransactionRequest` class.

How do I enforce this with types?

```
export enum RequestMethod {
  SendTransaction = 'sendTransaction',
  RequestAccounts = 'requestAccounts',
  Other = 'other',
  // ...
}

interface RequestProps {
  id: number;
  method: RequestMethod;
  payload: ???;
}

export class Request {
  private constructor(props: RequestProps)
    this.props = Object.freeze(props);
  }

  public getID(): number {
    return this.props.id;
  }

  public getMethod(): RequestMethod {
    return this.props.method;
  }

  public getPayload(): ??? {
    return this.props.payload;
  }

  public static create(props: RequestProps): Request {
    return new Request(props);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use typescript `type` for this purpose.

You must enforce some limited allowed combination of types as follows:

```
type SendTransactionRequest = string;
type RequestAccountsRequest = number;

type RequestMethod = "SendTransaction" | "RequestAccounts" | "Other";

type RequestProps = {
  id: number;
} & (
  | {
      method: "SendTransaction";
      payload: SendTransactionRequest;
    }
  | {
      method: "RequestAccounts";
      payload: RequestAccountsRequest;
    }
);
```

With this type definition, all `RequestProps` will have an `id`, but there are only certain allowed combinations of `method` and `payload` allowed.

```
// valid
const m1: RequestProps = {
    id: 0,
    method: 'RequestAccounts',
    payload: 0,
}

// valid
const m2: RequestProps = {
    id: 0,
    method: 'SendTransaction',
    payload: '',
}

// error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
const m3: RequestProps = {
    id: 0,
    method: 'RequestAccounts',
    payload: '',
}

// error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
const m4: RequestProps = {
    id: 0,
    method: 'SendTransaction',
    payload: 0,
}
```

---

If you then what to type the `Request` class to have the correct return type for `getPayload()` you need to use generics:

```
export class Request<Props extends RequestProps = RequestProps> {
  props: Props;

  private constructor(props: Props) {
    this.props = Object.freeze(props);
  }

  public getID(): number {
    return this.props.id;
  }

  public getMethod(): RequestMethod {
    return this.props.method;
  }

  public getPayload(): Props["payload"] {
    return this.props.payload;
  }

  public static create<Props extends RequestProps>(
    props: Props
  ): Request<Props> {
    return new Request(props);
  }
}

const req = Request.create({
  id: 0,
  method: "SendTransaction",
  payload: "",
});

const payload = req.getPayload() // string
```

Comment: Thank you. How do I type the getPayload() return value then?

Comment: You need to use generics in this case, I added an example to the answer

Comment: If I have a property `let request: Request`  and I check `if (request.getMethod() === 'SendTransaction')`, I would expect request.payload inside the if block to be typed as `string`, but it still types as `string | number`. Is there a way I can get the proper type in this scenario?

Comment: I don’t think is possible. Typescript seems unable to narrow down the type of a method based on the result of another method. If that is the requirement, I would avoid using a class and use types directly.